# NumberFormatException in GSON for valid double number

Tags: java, json, gson

Input JSON:

```
 "coordinates":[
               ​9.40323,
               ​56.45364
            ]
```

I'm getting number format exception while using gson even if number is valid

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "​9.40323"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextDouble(JsonReader.java:925)
    at com.google.gson.Gson$3.read(Gson.java:259)
    at com.google.gson.Gson$3.read(Gson.java:253)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:72)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:696)
```

My GSON version is 2.3.1 and locale is en_US. 
GSON object is created as

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder(); 

        // Register an adapter to manage the date types as long values 
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() { 
           public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
              return new Date(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsLong());
           } 
        });

        Gson gson = builder.create();
```

Comment: I'm not converting double to date. that adapter is for different attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string contains some special characters. It looks like just digits but there is three extra bytes at the start.

```
$ od -xc
"​9.40323"
0000000    e222    8b80    2e39    3034    3233    2233    000a
          " 342 200 213   9   .   4   0   3   2   3   "  \n
0000015
```

If this comes in as a String you can strip non-ASCII characters with

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
```

Comment: it is a zero width space (U+200B).

Comment: Thanks.. this is the issue. But any idea how do i get rid of this space. I retyped 2 number by removing spaces and it worked for them but i've lots of them in my source. I tried using online json formatters but it did not help

Comment: @Pranalee you need to filter out these characters first.  Is this coming as a String, Reader or InputStream.